How to scale subplots including images with different aspect ratios?
A minimal version of my problem is the following plot. How do I scale the right panel to have the same height as the left one?
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

rnd = np.random.default_rng(123)

dx1, dy1 = 3, 2
dx2, dy2 = 3, 4

im1 = rnd.random((dy1, dx1))
im2 = rnd.random((dy2, dx2))

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

ax1.imshow(im1)
ax2.imshow(im2)


I could position both plots by hand, but I need a robust procedure to generate multiple similar plots. I looked at ImageGrid and GridSpec but neither seems to support what I need. I would expect subplots to automatically do what I need, but this is not the case. Is this behaviour by design?

Ensure that both axes have the same height by setting a consistent aspect ratio
ax1.set_box_aspect(1)  # 1:1 aspect ratio for the box (height/width ratio)
ax2.set_box_aspect(1)  # 1:1 aspect ratio for the box (height/width ratio)

Thanks, this would work. If I set ax2.set_box_aspect(.7), both plots have the same height and aspect ratio. However, this creates unnecessary white space above/below the right plot. Is there a way to force the plots to have the same height rather than the same width, without changing the respective aspect ratios?

Yes.  Make the figure wider

@Jody how? The width of the two figures in the subplots is fixed.

I finally found the solution fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, width_ratios=[.7, 1])

plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(width, height)...

@Jody changing the figure size won't change the aspect ratio of the subplots. The right panel remains taller than the left. Try it.

The solution consists of using the width_ratios keyword of plt.subplots
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

rnd = np.random.default_rng(123)

dx1, dy1 = 3, 2
dx2, dy2 = 3, 4

im1 = rnd.random((dy1, dx1))
im2 = rnd.random((dy2, dx2))

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, width_ratios=[dx1/dy1, dx2/dy2])

ax1.imshow(im1)
ax2.imshow(im2)


